# Take a photo via usb on android phone

Tags: android, microcontroller, photo

I want to take a photo on an android mobile, to local storage, controlled from a microcontroller.

The solutions requirements:

- The image must be a good quality, so I think the remote solutions aren't perfect
- The pictures take on different devices.
- The control must be based on the conditions of a microcontroller.

I open for all solutions, but I don't work with a professional team, so I would prefer simpler solutions

Thanks

Comment: By clicking a button on the microcontroller circuit, you have to take a photo from an Android device that's right ?

Comment: a bit more complicated measurements (e.g. humidity), but essentially yes

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to modify the selfie stick so I don't need to run software on the phone and I get a relatively easy to use solution. The downside is that not all phones are compatible with all selfie sticks (for example: jack, usb C etc.)

With this solution I might give some ideas to others.

*Thanks for the help Abdo21*